# Can only open documents once from Sharepoint

Tags: 2010, document-library, document, office-integration, office-2016

I hope someone can help.

I have a client using SharePoint 2010 On-Prem with Office 2016. They are due to upgrade SharePoint next year (to Online I think). They are using Internet Explorer Version is 11.0.9600.19236. Update Versions: 11.0.105 to try and access Documents from their SharePoint Library.

Currently you can go into the Document Library, and click on a Document to open it. You get asked of you want to edit the document or open Read-Only. Your are then prompted for an ID and Password and, once authenticated, the Document will open in Word for example.

You can edit and save the document back to SharePoint without issue.

If you close the document then try to access it again, Word will start but the Document doesn't load. Nothing happens beyond Word starting up.

Done a bit of looking around and followed some advice to delete the `FSD` and `FSF` files in `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\16.0\OfficeFileCache` on my local machine. This allows me to open the document one more time. But the next time I try I am faced with the same issue. This feels like I'm on the right track to a solution but it's not the full solution.

Any and all assistance greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Dan.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get an authentication prompt on the second try?
If not: Sounds like an authentication problem :)

Can you disable "Modern Authentication" on one of the client machines, reboot the client machine and then try it again?

To disable "Modern Authentication", create a new REG_DWORD on the client machine under *HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Identity* with regedit.

- Name: EnableADAL
- Value: 0

Source: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/modern-authentication-on-outlook-2016-keeps-on/98a263f4-ab9c-4d6f-b5eb-2728a8e77412?auth=1

Comment: Hi Engineerer. On the second try there is no authentication prompt, Word loads but nothing else happens. Not even a blank empty Document. Thanks for the suggestion, I've asked the Client to disable Modern Authentication on one machine and see what happens. Will update the ticket when I know more......Dan